# Length of 1D curves using 2D integration with $\delta$

Tags: integration, geometry

Let the equation $f(x,y)=0$ describe some simple curve in the $x,y$-plane. I had the expectation that the length of this curve between $x_1$ and $x_2$ could be written as
$$ \int_{x_1}^{x_2} dx\int_{-\infty}^\infty dy \delta(f(x,y)),$$
in the sense that the $\delta$ would pick up the points in the curve.

This works for a circumference, $f(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-R$ since
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx\int_{-\infty}^\infty dy \delta(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-R)=2\pi \int_0^\infty rdr\delta(r-R)=2\pi R.$$

Does it work in general? The length should be 
$$ \int_{x_1}^{x_2} dx \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2},$$ 
I don't see that this equals my first integral.

Comment: If anything it will measure something similar to taxicab distance and not euclidean distance.

Answer (score 0):

The length of (a closed) curve would be:

$$L=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(f(x,y))\sqrt{(\partial_xf)^2+(\partial_yf)^2}dxdy$$

Comment: How would one prove this?

Comment: Using the delta function identities on Wikipedia

Comment: Can you be more specific?